# Sanitize ACF WYSIWYG Content in Automattic's AMP plugin

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, amp-html

I use the [ACF Flexible Content field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/flexible-content/) with subfields (WYSIWYG, etc) to build custom pages/CPT posts in Wordpress. I am using a custom child theme with AMP templates using the [AMP for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amp/) plugin by Automattic.

I am trying to sanitize the output of an ACF WYSIWYG field so that `<img>` tags are converted to `<amp-img>` tags.

By default, the AMP plugin sanitizes `the_content` to replace certain tags so that they validate for AMP. Since the ACF WYSIWYG field content is outside of `the_content`, it is not being sanitized. Has anyone been able to sanitize custom fields so that the AMP validator finds no errors?

Answer (score 1):

HTML in custom fields is, from my point of view, a weird use case of custom fields. Even more, if the purpose of the used HTML is just looking and feel (`<strong>`, `<img>` and `<i>` can be seen as just look and feel). It is really better if you use the HTML markup on the custom field output or if you use CSS to apply bold/italic styles.

That being said, you can try to use [PHP strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php) function or [wp_kses() function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses). Both allow you to strip HTML tags but allow some of them. Example using `wp_kses()`:

```
$allow_html_tag = array(
    'i' => array(),
    'strong' => array(),
    'img' => array(),
);

if( isset( $_POST['my_field'] ) ){

    $meta_value = wp_kses( $_POST['my_field'], $allow_html_tag);

    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_field', $meta_value );

}
```

Comment: I've edited the original question in hopes to provide clarification. As a temporary solution, I am currently using `strip_tags()` to remove all `<img>` tags in the WYSIWYG fields.

Comment: Use wp_laws() function